# Can DecimalFormat be used to centralise the decimal point?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I can achieve the following using `DecimalFormat("0000.00000000");`, e.g.

```
0000.00000028
0001.23450000
1234.56000012
0314.15000000
```

But can I achieve the following?

```
   0.00000028
   1.23450000
1234.56000012
 314.15000000
```

I want to basically centre everything about the decimal point. I tried a few combinations but could not find a solution. On the other hand, I am aware of `String.format`.

Comment: While an FAQ, I haven't seen anyone explain why it can't be done natively. The answer is that `DecimalFormat` does not support space padding by design, and the RFE to add it has been closed with a clunky workaround instead: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4248151

A less clunky method is the `printf` style: `System.out.print(String.format("%14.8f\n", number));`

where 8 is the number of digits after the decimal point and 13 is the total number of characters, including any leading spaces, the digits and the decimal point.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thanks.